# Number of products displayed in HelloSlide homepage block in Magento 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, magento

http://bit.ly/bsydBA

I've widened the product slider displaying boots to be full page width but I'm not seeing how to expand the number of products being displayed neither vía CSS or the code in featured.phtml (below). I also haven't found anything in the admin which would let me set any parameters.

The site just came to me after a variety of prior developers got under the hood so I'm just wrapping my head around any changes made to core files (yes, they didn't use /app/code/local/).

Has anyone worked with theme or see where I might be able to make the required adjustment?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="note-msg">
    <?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection. Please provide a category ID.') ?>
 </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
 <ul id="featured" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if($i++%4==0): ?>


            <?php endif ?>



         <li><a class="preview" rel="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300, 300); ?>" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(105, 105); ?>" width="105" height="105" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                </a> </li>

        <?php if ($i%4==0 && $i!=$_collectionSize): ?>

        <?php endif ?>


<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: can you please also post the code of the page (CMS page code) that includes featured.phtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  Turns out the site was using GTSpeed to minify the JS and CSS and cache them so the changes that I made in Firebug just didn't appear.

Once I figured this out and disabled it was a snap, just needed to change

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal for the outer container
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal for the inner container